# How Can i expose my app maker apps to users from outside of my organization

Tags: google-app-maker

I would like to generate an app with app maker that wiil be available as a saas product for any internet user. Is that possible?

Sharon

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not possible. You can find more details in App Maker documentation:
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment#application_publishing